# 49 years throttle time for firebase remote config

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I tried using the firebase remote config for the first time. Maybe I should have read all the document that I have to enable the debug mode. But I didn't do that and I made like 7-9 requests.

Now I keep end up with the FetchThrottledException with message

```
Fetching throttled, try again in -1559071599705 milliseconds
```

which is around 49 years.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can solve this or am I doing something wrong? I wanted to get in contact with Google, but Firebase does not provide easy access to technical support.

Comment: The easy access to support (if it doesn't fit into a known category) is at the bottom of this page: https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: Now you need to wait 49 years to try again to see if it will work!

Answer (score 0):

It's good that I don't have to wait 49 years for this. I was able to solve the problem by deleting the app of my device and reinstalling it.